# list as member in a class

Tags: c++

I am having some trouble! My goal is to check an input number against a list of prime numbers to see if it is prime (in the list) via the `find()` function. I haven't gotten that far yet. This is homework so I have to overload the function operator and do it in this dumb (imho) way. Here is what I have thus far:

```
using namespace std;

class isprime {
    public: isprime() { /*nothing...yet?*/
    }
    bool operator()(int);
    list <int> pnums(1, 2);

    private: int expandList(int number);
};

bool isprime::operator()(int number) {
    if (pnums.back() < number) {}
}

int isprime::expandList(int number) {
    for (int j = pnums.back(); j = number; j++) {
        for (int i = 2; i < sqrt(j); i++) {
            if (j % i != 0) pnums.push_back(j);
        }

    }
}

int main() {
    isprime pcheck;
    int number;

    while (cin >> number) {
        if (pcheck(number)) cout << number << " is prime!\n";
    }
}
```

Here are my errors:

> prime2.cpp:12: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
>   prime2.cpp:12: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric
>   constant
>  prime2.cpp: In member function 'bool
>   isprime::operator()(int)':
>  prime2.cpp:19: error:
>   '((isprime*)this)->isprime::pnums' does not have class type
>   prime2.cpp: In member function 'int isprime::expandList(int)':
>   prime2.cpp:23: error: '((isprime*)this)->isprime::pnums' does not have
>   class type
>  prime2.cpp:25: error:
>   '((isprime*)this)->isprime::pnums' does not have class type

I don't understand what is going wrong. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Revise how class definitions work, in particular how you declare class members.

Comment: 1 error at a time, and try figuring it out yourself. It's much more useful than us coming in and providing you with the corrected version.

Comment: google hint: constructor initializer list

Comment: one more: `list.back` is a method, therefore: `list.back()`

Comment: and one question, why would you consider it 'dumb': i like function objects! clearly, it is a learning exercise, which are often 'strange', but nevertheless!

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I understand that concept. I have been tinkering with the first error for awhile now. I'm not looking for answers, just some guidance because I feel like I'm banging my head against a brick wall

Comment: @RudolfMühlbauer I consider it dumb simply because this code: `#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

bool isprime(int number)
{
    for (int i=2;i<sqrt(number)+0.4;i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {return false;}
    }
    if (number < 2) {return false;}

    return true;
};

int main()
{
    int number;
    while (cin >> number) {
      if (isprime(number))
        cout << number << " is prime!\n";
    }
}`

does exactly what I want to do, and is much easier! Also, thank you for the tip.

Comment: @RudolfMühlbauer also, are you saying I need to initialize the list in the initialization list? Because when I don't try to give the list any arguments the compiler is happy

Comment: @dockleryxk: initializer list: exactly. that is the position to put parameters for your class members' constructors. dumb or not: it is still homework ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem is how you are trying use the constructor for the list in your class. If you simply remove `(1, 2)` from the list declaration in your class, it should compile. Second, if you want to call the constructor of an object in your class, I recommend this method

```
class isprime{
  public: 
   isprime() : pnums(1,2) { /*nothing...yet?*/ }
   ...
   list <int> pnums;
   ...
```

Comment: Niiiiice!! I had this figured out by the time you posted it, but THANK YOU because my instructor provides a makefile for us to compile our code with and I kept getting all of these crazy errors, however it was due to my compiler being happy with my code and not so happy with a different code in the directory. Long story short this response gave me the confidence of knowing my method was correct